# Placing a Div between a Left and Right floated Div if there is space, placing it below them if there is not enough space

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float

I'm working on a navbar for a website, like your average navbar, It has a logo (float: left), links to other pages, and account setting at the end (float: right), all side by side. When the window gets resized, I want to be able to still have all elements of the navbar present without having to scroll horizontally. I want to do this by placing all the links to the pages below the logo (and still have account setting at the top right).

At Full-screen the navbar work perfectly (simple enough). When the window is resized everything gets messed up (last div ends up out of window).

[The two top images are illustrations of what im working towards, and the third one down is my current issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3phJ.png)

I have some experience in css, but understanding how to fix this (or look up how to fix this) is beyond my abilities. I would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: You can solve this with a combination of "CSS grid" and media queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attached code snippet, is a base that uses "CSS grid" and media queries. There are some duplicates in the CSS that could with more time spent, be improved, thus minimize the code. It gives you an idea about how these layouts are built.

```css
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  1fr
  ;
  grid-template-rows:
  100px
  100px
  100px
  ;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header-1"
  "header-2"
  "content"
  ;
}

.header-1 {
  grid-area: header-1;
  background-color: grey;
}

.header-2 {
  grid-area: header-2;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.header-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  1fr
  1fr
  1fr
  ;
  grid-template-rows:
  100px
  ;
  grid-template-areas:
  "box-1 box-2 box-3"
  ;
}


.box-1 {
  grid-area: box-1;
  background-color: magenta;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box-2 {
  grid-area: box-2;
  background-color: cyan;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box-3 {
  grid-area: box-3;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

}

 @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

   .wrapper {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns:
     1fr
     ;
     grid-template-rows:
     100px
     100px
     100px
     ;
     grid-template-areas:
     "header-1"
     "header-2"
     "content"
     ;
   }

   .header-1 {
     grid-area: header-1;
     background-color: grey;
   }

   .header-2 {
     grid-area: header-2;
     background-color: grey;
   }

   .content {
     grid-area: content;
     background-color: lightgrey;
   }

   .header-1 {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns:
     1fr
     1fr
     1fr
     ;
     grid-template-rows:
     100px
     ;
     grid-template-areas:
     "box-1 . box-3"
     ;
   }

   .header-2 {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns:
     1fr
     1fr
     1fr
     ;
     grid-template-rows:
     100px
     ;
     grid-template-areas:
     "box-2 box-2 box-2"
     ;
   }


   .box-1 {
     grid-area: box-1;
     background-color: magenta;
     margin: 10px;
   }

   .box-2 {
     grid-area: box-2;
     background-color: cyan;
   }

   .box-3 {
     grid-area: box-3;
     background-color: green;
     margin: 10px;
   }

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header-1">
        <div class="box-1"></div>
        <div class="box-2"></div>
        <div class="box-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="header-2">
      <div class="box-1"></div>
      <div class="box-2"></div>
      <div class="box-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="content"></div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for... I just had to change "max-width" to "min-width" and vise versa and it works perfectly. Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you find it useful. Thanks.

Comment: way ahead of you m'dude :D